# wifi keeps disconnecting on ubuntu 20.04 LTS with RT3290

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04

My wifi keeps disconnecting and I think it's because I don't have the right driver. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 with a Ralink rt3290. I've searched over the web and installed r8168-dkms, but it didn't change anything for me.

Comment: You've installed a Realtek driver but you have a Ralink chipset. It did nothing as expected. Yours is already supported and there's no other driver. If it isn't working as expected the first to check is the router: WPA2-AES is preferred, not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I should have probably mentioned that, but I'm new on ubuntu. How do I check what security mode I have? And what are the logs? Also, the network is not mine, I live in a building and the wifi is the same for everyone.

Comment: Ok I've checked, there is no security.